# JavaFX load image from external folder

Tags: java, image, javafx, path, directory

I need some help with importing Images to my JavaFx application:

My image has the path : /sprinter/ExternalSprinterFolder/Maps/map_asteroid/map_asteroid.jpg

My GUI code has the path:
/sprinter/src/de/sprinter/gameclient/gui/SelectSectorGui.java

I tried already a lot but I can't load the image...
I tried for example:

```
File file = new File(imagePath);
Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
```

and

```
 String image = SelectSectorGui.class.getResource(imagePath).toExternalForm();
 pane.setStyle(("-fx-background-image: url(\" " + image +
                      " \");-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code block is the correct way to do this if the file will be on the file system, and not bundled as part of your jar file. In that case `imagePath` should be the absolute filesystem path to the file. You can check if the file exists with

```
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

The second code block is the correct way to do this if the image file will be bundled in your jar file. In this case, `imagePath` should be relative to the class; an path starting with `/` is interpreted as being relative to the classpath. If the path is incorrect in this case, `getResource(...)` will return `null`.